# How to do Javadoc on Java enums that have extra attributes?

Tags: java, enums, javadoc

One topic that I can't seem to find information on is how to do Javadoc for enums that have an extra parameter.  For example in the classic Coins example how can the 1,5,10,25 values be associated with penny, nickle, dime, quarter (other that keying each in by hand)?

```
 enum Coin {
     PENNY(1),
     NICKEL(5),
     DIME(10),
     QUARTER(25);

   private final int denomValue;

   Coin(int denomValue) {
       this.denomValue = denomValue;
   }

   int denomValue() {
      return denomValue;
   }

   int toDenomination(int numPennies) {
      return numPennies / denomValue;
   }
}
```

A typical use case is documenting error mnemonics and int error codes.

Comment: Why do the extra parameters need to be in a javadoc.  The values in the constructor (and the fact the constructor takes any arguments) are all implementation details that external classes shouldn't care about. That denomValue method should be documented sure but how it gets its value isn't important

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work for you or am I misunderstanding the question?

```
/**
 * blah blah
 */
enum Coin {
    /**
     * Penny - 1 cent, blah blah
     */
    PENNY(1),

    /**
     * Nickel - 5 cents, blah blah 
     */
    NICKEL(5),
    ...
```

Comment: Javadoc has always been a cut above something like JsDoc (for JavaScript) because it usually provide the means to cross-reference the actual signature via @param, or similar.  This way you don't have to maintain and synchronize all the code.  If the enum set gets big, sooner or later the Javadoc or enums will be wrong.  The typical example is association of fault literals with fault integers:

Comment: Radoh, in your example you had to make (1) a literal copy of the enum symbol (e.g., NICKEL) and (2) its value (e.g., 5).  This seems like a lot of manual cut-n-paste and lots of room for error.  Aren't there any cross-reference techniques?

Comment: I see. I know only of `{@value}` which cannot really be used here. I don't know if anything like you ask exists...